# 2010 : Problem in authenticating CSOM C# code

Tags: 2010, csom, authentication

I am working with SharePoint 2010 with Client Side Object Model (C#).

I am able to login in Browser but with the same credential I am not able to login with `CSOM C#` Code.

I am getting

```
401 Unauthorized Access
```

What should be possible reason I need to verify?

What I tried:-

- I tried supplying `clientContext.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.Default;`. Still the issue is same. I can confirm that the site does not uses Form Based Authentication.

Please provide your valuable suggestions.

Comment: you can try $clientContext.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using following code:

```
clientContext clientContext = new clientContext(siteUrl);
CredentialCache myCache = new CredentialCache();
myCache.Add(new Uri(siteUrl), "Your Authentication Type", new NetworkCredential(userName, password));
clientContext.Credentials = myCache;
```

Please let me know if it works.

Comment: I It worked. I used "NTLM" at the place of "Your Authentication Type" :-)